# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a Darboux function so that $f(f(x))$ is injective. Show that $f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

I came across this problem and I can't really show that $f$ is continuous in a.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a Darboux function so that $f(f(x))$ is injective on $(-\infty , a)$ and on $(a,\infty)$, where $a$ is a real number.
Show that $f$ is continuous and that if $f$ touches 0, it is in $a$.
($f(x)=0 <=> f(a)=0$)

So far, I said that because $f(f(x))$ is injective, then $f$ is bijective. Because f is a Darboux function, then $f(f(X))$ is a Darboux function. Because it is injective on the given intervals, then $f$ must be strictly increasin on those intervals. I also said that because $f$ is bijective and monotonous, then it is continuous on those intervals. I am yet to show that f is continuous in a, which I can't crack yet.

Comment: Perhaps you should add the definition of a Darboux function.

Comment: $f$ has the intermediate value property: for any two values $a$ and $b$ in the domain of $f$, and any y between f(a) and f(b), there is some c between a and b with $f(c) = y$

Comment: Thank you, but in my comment I wanted to suggest that you add this information to your question ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by claiming that $f$ is bijective. What is the logical progression from $f\circ f$ injective to $f$ bijective?

What we do know easily is that if $\forall x,y\in S:f(f(x))=f(f(y))\implies x=y$ holds, then $f$ satisfies $\forall x,y\in S:f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$.

Therefore $f$ is **injective** on the given intervals.

As you probably know, given that $f$ is Darboux, the function $f$ is continuous on $(-\infty,a)$ and **either is strictly increasing on the interval or strictly decreasing on the interval**. Same goes for $(a,\infty)$.

If $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, can $f$ be Darboux?

For example, let's say $f$ strictly increases on $(-\infty,a)$. Then $f(x)$ has a **left-limit** at $x=a$, either to some $r\in\mathbb{R}$ or going to $+\infty$.

Draw this on a graph to find out why, if this left-limit is greater than $f(a)$ or smaller than $f(a)$, then $f$ cannot be Darboux.

Then check the same for the case where $f$ decreases on this interval, and almost the same argument applies to the other interval.

$\\$

Also, as an aside: the conclusion $\exists x: f(x)=0\implies f(a)=0$ does not follow from the conditions given in the question. Choose $f(x)=-x$ and $a\neq0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying. I had assumed that from the injectivity of $f(f(x))$ it follows the bijectivity of $f$, not only the injectivity. My mistake.  And also, I also found other counterexamples. The problem just states that if there exists $x$ such that $f(x)=0$  then $x=a$. Again, thank you.